# Label Alignment

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

```
for(int j=0;j<featuresKeyCount;j++)     {
    NSString *str1=[featuresKey objectAtIndex:j];
    NSString *str2=[str1 stringByAppendingString: @":"];   
}
```

In the above code i am getting

```
str1= Phone No
      Projector
      VCD
      LCD
      Polycom
      Digital Phone
      Speaker Phone

In str2 = Phone No:
      Projector:
      VCD:
      LCD:
      Polycom:
      Digital Phone:
      Speaker Phone:
```

But i want output like this :

```
                                 Phone No     :
                                 Projector    :
                                 VCD          :
                                 LCD          :
                                 Polycom      :
                                 Digital Phone:
                                 Speaker Phone:
```

Any suggestions for this .

Answer (score 1):

You will never get same spaces in text even when you count number of characters from the longest of string.

Say the length comes to 3. Then "aaa" and "iii" the length/size teken by these two will not be same, as each character takes different spaces.

Possible solution would be like :

Making two textFields for an object, as

```
"First                "  ":"
"Second               "  ":"
"This is too long to  "  ":"
```

Make first label long enough and store only text, its counterpart with only ":".

Or Another way would be to right-align(But this is not preferred by apple guidelines), as:

```
"                First:"  
"               Second:"  
"  This is too long to:"
```

Comment: Any suggestions for right alignment .I want to do right alignment.

Comment: Right alignment is the style I follwed in Visual Basic applications not in Mac applications. However right-align is very simple, make your nstextfield long enough to store the longest of string.